# Java 8 deflator, best compression and default compression compatible?

Tags: java, zlib

I am exploring if i can change compression level of compression.
I think the level shouldn't affect compatibility, i.e, when decompressing, deflator can handle both best and default compression level, but wanted to confirm there is no gotchas.

I am aware that there is additional processing time needed to do best compression, but is the same true when decompressing?

thanks

Comment: can you pass compression level during inflation?

Comment: I'd say it depends on your use case and that you should benchmark it. JMH might help to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Decompression is a smidge *faster* for more highly compressed data, simply because there is less compressed data to process.